# How do I know if a position is in a region using python

Tags: python

I have 2 files.

File A has 3 columns: chromosome,start position,end position.

```
CHR,START,END
chr1,1203245,1203374
chr1,1202020,1202213
chr1,1201293,1201465
chr1,1200844,1201128
chr1,1200527,1200585
```

File B has 2 columns: chromosome,position.

```
CHR,POS
chr1,1579264
chr1,1641372
chr1,3020521
chr2,2097836
chr3,2374462
```

Both files are large.

How do I decide every position of file B is in any region of file A using python? I can write code if there is just one position and one region, but I don't have a clue for a list of region.

`Position is in a region` means `CHR` should be same and `POS >= START and POS <= END`, for example, `chr1,1203250` of file B should be in `chr1,1203245,1203374` of file A

I take oscarbranson's advice and write code:

```
for i,r in B.iterrows():
    B.loc[i, 'in_A'] = any((r.CHR == A.CHR) & (r.POS >= A.SATRT) & (r.POS <= A.END))
```

But both of 2 files are large and the code is still running. If there is any way to make this faster?

Comment: Can you please show us an example of any inputs and outputs by editing your question? [edit]

Comment: I guess regular expressions will do. In order to give you an example we must know what is the relation between the POS column and START/END. Would you be kind enough to update your question again explaining what is a match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If your files are big you *cannot* just load both in a dataframe, as it would fill your entire memory.
2. Do *not* compare the position of B to every interval in A, because this is terribly inefficient (understand: very very slow).

Instead, do this:

1. Sort both files by chrom, start, end.
2. Iterate on lines of both files concurrently. Something like this (for the idea; it does not take the chromosome into account, and may have bugs in it, plus you need to define the way you save the position):

   ```
   a = open("A")
   b = open("B")
   # init
   (chromA,start,end) = a.readline().split(",")
   (chromB,pos) = b.readline().split(",")
   while 1:
       try:
           if pos < start:
               # Read more lines from B
               (chromB,pos) = b.readline().split(",")
           elif pos > end:
               # Read more lines from A
               (chromA,start,end) = a.readline().split(",")
           else:
               # Pos is in the [start, end] interval
               # Save the result and go to the next pos
               savePos()  
               (chromB,pos) = b.readline().split(",")
       except StopIteration:
           break
   ```

My real advice though would be to not do this manually like every bioinformatician in the past, but to use "bedtools" or existing Python libraries like BioPython. Reinventing the wheel is a terrible loss of time and resources for research.

Answer (score -1):

I've interpreted your question as 'are the POS values in each row of B between any of the START and END values in all rows of A?' If that's correct, something like this will work, using the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) data analysis library:

```
import pandas as pd

A = pd.read_csv('path/to/A.csv')
B = pd.read_csv('path/to/B.csv')

for i, r in B.iterrows():
    B.loc[i, 'in_A'] = any((r.POS > A.START) & (r.POS < A.END))

print(B)

>>     CHR      POS   in_A
    0  chr1  1579264  False
    1  chr1  1641372  False
    2  chr1  3020521  False
    3  chr2  2097836  False
    4  chr3  2374462  False
```

This iterates through every row in B, and generates a boolean array that is TRUE where (POS > START) & (POS < END) for all rows of A. It then makes a new column in the B dataframe, which is True if POS exists within *any* of the START/END limits in A.

Make sense?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I use pandas like this: ` B.loc[i, 'in_A'] = any((r.CHR == A.CHR) & (r.POS >= A.SATRT) & (r.POS <= A.END))`, but it is too slow. Any advice to make this faster?

Comment: It is slow because this answer compares every position to every interval in the other file, so it grows as length(A) x length(B). If you sort the files before, you can come up with something more clever. And this loads both files entirely in memory; the OP says they are "large" and if they really were this would never work.